# How to create multidimensional array with key value pair php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays like this :

Array 1 is having x-axis values in array y-axis values in array

```
x-array: ["04 Feb","05 Feb","06 Feb","07 Feb","08 Feb","09 Feb","10 Feb"]
y-array: [3.27,3.34,3.27,3.2,3.28,3.17,3.15]
```

Array2 is having x-axis values in array y-axis values in array

```
x-array2: ["11 Feb", "12 Feb"]
y-array2: [3.19, 3.36]
```

How to create multidimensional array with key value pair.

Like below in php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [x-axis] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 04 Feb
                    [1] => 05 Feb
                    [2] => 06 Feb
                    [3] => 07 Feb
                    [4] => 08 Feb
                    [5] => 09 Feb
                    [6] => 10 Feb
                )

            [y-axis] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3.27
                    [1] => 3.34
                    [2] => 3.27
                    [3] => 3.2
                    [4] => 3.28
                    [5] => 3.17
                    [6] => 3.15
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [x-axis] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11 Feb
                    [1] => 12 Feb
                )

            [y-axis] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3.19
                    [1] => 3.36
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: whats wrong with 12 Feb?

Comment: @Bhavik Shah missed it while pasting.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$new_array = array(array("x-axis"=>$x-axis-array,
                         "y-axis"=>$y-axis-array
                        ),
                   array("x-axis"=>$x-axis-array2,
                         "y-axis"=>$y-axis-array2
                        )
                  );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
  0 => array(
    "x-axis" => $x_array,
    "y-axis" => $y_array),
  1 => array(
    "x-axis" => $x_array2,
    "y-axis" => $y_array2)
) ;

var_dump($array) ;
```